# Fill NaN with mean value with group by

Tags: python, dataframe, nan

my dataset looks like this

```
Month DayOfWeek  Class A1  A2 ... A999
July  Monday     Bata  7   9  ... 5
July  Tuesay     Bata  3   1  ... 2
July  Sunday     Bata  4   5  ... 6
July  Monday     Adid  9   8  ... 5
July  Sunday     Adid  4   0  ... 4
Sept  Monday     Nike  7   5  ... 7
Sept  Sunday     Nike  8   3  ... 7
Sept  Satday     Adid  2   7  ... 7
Sept  Monday     Bata  8   9  ... 4
Oct   Monday     Nike  4   2  ... 5
Oct   Sunday     Bata  8   6  ... 3
July  Monday     Nike  NaN NaN    NaN
Sept  Sunday     Nike  NaN NaN    NaN
Oct   Satday     Nike  NaN NaN    NaN
Sept  Monday     Bata  NaN NaN    NaN
```

I want to fill **NaNs** with average value of the previous records

I know that I can use

```
df['A1'] = df['A1'].fillna((df['A1'].mean()))
```

but this is a bad way because I have more than 1000 columns and they may increase later on

add to that

I want to find the mean based on Month and DayOfWeek

for this record

```
July  Monday     Nike  NaN NaN    NaN
```

therefore the average will be only the average of the records that has **Month = July & DayOfWeek = Monday**

how can i do that?

Comment: Are you aware of multi level indexing (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)? I used them once in a similar problem, helped me a loot using drill downs to calculate similar KPIs as you are looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
df['A1'] = df.groupby(['Month','DayOfWeek'])['A1'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

The above will still give one null value because there is no value for "Month = Oct & DayOfWeek = Monday". 
In that case you may want to write a second code to fill with the average of that month or average of DayOfWeek.
The code snippet below fills nulls with average of the month of records with the null value:

```
df['A1'] = df.groupby('Month')['A1'].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Upvote if this helps

Comment: Thanks, but I loose Month and DayOfWeek columns after applying this line, they are not in the dataframe anymore?!! any solution for that?

Comment: I still have all columns intact when I ran those lines of code. Do you want to share what you wrote. running df= df.groupby('Month')....... instead of df['A1'] = df.groupby('Month')...... will make you lose other columns.